# Evaluate a game skill benefit

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I ask a same problem yesterday, but my post has so many grammar error.
I am very sorry about that! Sorry for my poor English.
So now I try to use more simple sentences for me to describe this problem again:

1. A player can fire magic ball, which has 4 second CD time
2. Magic ball will hit to an enemy, the hit rate depend on player skill
3. A magic ball has 15% chance to make a buff to the enemy, this buff will cause the enemy loses his 0.1% MAX-HP per second
4. An enemy can be made only one buff, and buff exist time, 10 second~40 second,  is depend on enemy's defend value
5. An enemy has a special skill, called "RB", can remove this buff immediately, this special skill has 60 second CD time

My question is that Now I have a skill, called "MA", which can increase 5% chance of buff making, it means that 15% => 20%.
How about the expected damage of skill "MA"?

==================================================================

I have some preliminary idea and I will try to describe them in follow:

I think this problem can make a math form -

(Expected Damage) = (Magic ball hit number)*(Magic ball hit rate)*(Buff chance)*(0.1% Enemy Max HP)*(Buff exist time)

Where

1. (Magic ball hit number) is a random variable depend on fire CD time, maybe a Poisson distribution
2. (Magic ball hit rate) is a random variable depend on player skill, maybe a logarithmic distribution, according to ELO evaluation.
3. (0.1% Enemy Max HP) is a random variable depend on average enemy's MAX HP
4. (Buff exist time) is a random variable depend on average enemy's defend value, a continuous random variable

I think this is Multiple-Random-Variable-Expected-Value problem, but I do not have any idea to evaluate it.

Please give me some tips or research direction.
Sorry for my poor English, and thank you very much!

PS: I do not know how to delete the old article, please help me to delete it, thanks a lot.

Comment: Ah, I think that the "RB" skill will affect (Buff exist time) very much

Comment: @JKAdolf, you could have "edited" the old post instead of posting a new one!

Comment: Ok, thank for your information